# How to bind socket to an interface in python (socket.SO_BINDTODEVICE missing)

Tags: python, sockets

This is probably a very simple thing.
I'm new to python so don't crucify me.

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, IN.SO_BINDTODEVICE, "eth1"+'\0')
```

the above command gives me:

```
NameError: name 'IN' is not defined
```

the only import I have is

```
import socket
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you don't understand the error message, it means you're referring a name `IN` which is not available at that point. Your code snippet is likely missing an [import](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm) statement.

The socket module may not offer SO_BINDTODEVICE for portability reasons. If you are absolutely sure that you're running on Linux that supports it, try replacing it with it's numerical value, which is `25`:

```
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, 25, "eth1"+'\0')
```

Or for python 3:

```
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, 25, str("eth1" + '\0').encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: I'm used to C and wanted to try doing this in python. Changing my import statement to "import socket, IN" fixed it.

Comment: If you're not using the socket module directly you can use monkey patching as described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585317/requests-bind-to-an-ip

Comment: The IN module is standard on linux platforms. It contains most constants from `/usr/include/netinet/in.h`. Sure enough, `SO_BINDTODEVICE` is set to 25 in that file.

Comment: The '\0' is necessary because the data is likely passed directly to the C API. If the name came from user input, I would also truncate the interface name to IF_NAMESIZE (16 including nul byte): `... , 25, ifname[:16]+'\0')`

Answer (score 3):

In `Python`, `SO_BINDTODEVICE` is present in `IN` module. Importing `IN` will solve the problem.

```
import socket
import IN

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, IN.SO_BINDTODEVICE, "eth0")
```

Answer (score 2):

You may even "export" a missing option:

```
if not hasattr(socket,'SO_BINDTODEVICE') :
    socket.SO_BINDTODEVICE = 25
```

then

```
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BINDTODEVICE, interface+'\0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware: SO_BINDTODEVICE won't work with packet sockets - Linux man-page [man 7 socket](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html)

> It is not supported for packet sockets (use normal [bind(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html) there).

Python-Example for eth1 with bind():

```
rawSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(3))
rawSocket.bind(('eth1',0))
```