# Requests, bind to an ip

Tags: python, urllib2, python-requests

I have a script that makes some requests with `urllib2`.

I use the trick [suggested elsewhere on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150332/source-interface-with-python-and-urllib2) to bind another ip to the application, where my my computer has two ip addresses (IP A and IP B).

I would like to switch to using the [`requests` library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html). Does anyone knows how I can achieve the same functionality with that library?

Comment: Have you tried the monkey patching method mentioned in the link you provided?  Did it not work?  I've never looked into the `requests` lib, but somewhere in there a socket must be getting created.

Comment: Requests uses urllib3 and it seems like the feature you're after belongs to the latter.

Answer (score 22):

Looking into the `requests` module, it looks like it uses `httplib` to send the http requests. `httplib` uses `socket.create_connection()` to connect to the www host.

Knowing that and following the monkey patching method in the link you provided:

```
import socket

real_create_conn = socket.create_connection

def set_src_addr(*args):
    address, timeout = args[0], args[1]
    source_address = ('IP_ADDR_TO_BIND_TO', 0)
    return real_create_conn(address, timeout, source_address)

socket.create_connection = set_src_addr

import requests
r = requests.get('http://www.google.com')
```

It looks like `httplib` passes all the arguments (to `create_connection()`) as args (vs keywords) as trying to extend the `kwargs` dict inside `set_src_addr` was failing.  I believe the above is what you want, but I don't have a dual homed machine to test on.

Comment: Yeah, just tested this too. Using `nc -nlvp 8080` I get the output of my default IP and not my bind IP.

Answer (score 1):

actually, you should **bind IP** to requests like this :

```
import urllib3
real_create_conn = urllib3.util.connection.create_connection

def set_src_addr(address, timeout, *args, **kw):
    source_address = ('YOUR_BIND_IP', 0)
    return real_create_conn(address, timeout=timeout, source_address=source_address)

urllib3.util.connection.create_connection = set_src_addr

import requests
r = requests.get('http://ipecho.net/plain')
print( r.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Reposting my answer from a duplicate question, as I believe it is a cleaner solution:

You can use a [SourceAddressAdapter](https://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/adapters.html#sourceaddressadapter) from requests-toolbelt:

```
import requests
from requests_toolbelt.adapters import source

source = source.SourceAddressAdapter('127.0.0.1')

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.mount('http://', source)
    r = session.get("http://example.com/foo/bar")
```