# Locust, How to set source request ip

Tags: locust

The virtual machine which run **Locust** has multiple network cards

Is there any way to set source request IP of **Locust**?

https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/configuration.html#command-line-options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible by monkey patching `socket.create_connection()` using the solution described here, as Locust’s HttpUser uses `requests`.

[Requests, bind to an ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585317/requests-bind-to-an-ip)

My original answer was deleted by a mod for some unknown reason. Lets hope it doesnt happen again...