# How to specify source IP address in python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, ip-address, nic

I have several IP addresses configured on my network interface card. I need to specify through which IP address python `requests` must connect to the web server. Is it possible?

```
import requests
r = requests.get("http://example.com/foo/bar")
```

I need to force `requests.get` to perform http request through a dasignated IP address.

Is there any other `http library` that support this feature in python?

Comment: It is possible but if you need help for the implementation you must be more specific about the devices and tools you use for it.

Comment: i think it's clear. if you have specific question, just ask

Comment: No, i have One interface with multi IP addresses. I don't have multi network interfaces

Comment: Probably this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585317/requests-bind-to-an-ip

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [SourceAddressAdapter](https://toolbelt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/adapters.html#sourceaddressadapter) from requests-toolbelt:

```
import requests
from requests_toolbelt.adapters import source

source = source.SourceAddressAdapter('127.0.0.1')

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.mount('http://', source)
    r = session.get("http://example.com/foo/bar")
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running a Django/Django-Rest project? Because, if so, you can just specify a custom host and port into the `python manage.py runserver` command! Like so:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001
```

Hope I understood the problem

Comment: Post updated. i don't use `Django`