# Python paramiko ssh.connect specify network interface to bind

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

With `paramiko.SSHClient()`, how can I specify the network interface to bind to. I'm referring to this argument in the ssh man page:

```
 -B bind_interface
             Bind to the address of bind_interface before attempting to
             connect to the destination host.  This is only useful on
             systems with more than one address.
```

In other words, I want to ssh like this `ssh -B en0 username@192.168.1.1` using `paramiko.SSHClient()`.

Answer (score 0):

Paramiko does not have native support for selecting the network interface.

But you can use `sock` parameter of [`SSHClient.connect`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect) to provide your own `socket` to use for the SSH connection.

For details how to bind Python `socket` to an interface, see:
[How to bind socket to an interface in python (socket.SO_BINDTODEVICE missing)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7221577/850848)

I didn't test it, but it *should* be like this:

```
import paramiko
import socket
import IN

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, IN.SO_BINDTODEVICE, str("en0" + '\0').encode('utf-8'))
sock.connect(("192.168.1.1", 22))
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect("192.168.1.1", username=username, sock=sock, ...)
```